# How to create a function that applies to the element Id tagged by an eventlistener?

Tags: javascript

Here is a snippet of code I am working with:

```
for(var i = 0; i < hexArray.length; i++) { 
    document.getElementById(hexArray[i]).addEventListener('animationend', wave, false);
    document.getElementById(hexArray[i]).addEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd', wave, false);
};
```

What I am trying to do is make wave a function variable that applies only to the current element Id the eventListener triggered off of.

So for instance, when the animation ends I want to tell the the wave function to run but only on the div that the animation that just ended.

Comment: Your event function can detect what element the event was called on.  The value of `this` will be the element the function was bound to.  In the case of child elements, `event.target` will be the element, and `this` will still be the parent.  See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/fHmc7/1/

Comment: Ahh thank you, I wasnt sure if I would have had to convert the whole thing to OOP to be able to use `this`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `wave` function, the value of `this` will be the element which the animation has just finished on.

Comment: Ahh thank you, I wasnt sure if I would have had to convert the whole thing to OOP to be able to use `this`